# HTML - Arabic Support

Tags: html, arabic, multilingual

i have a website in which i have to put some lines in Arabic.... how to do it...

where to get the Arabic text characters... how to make the page support Arabic...

i have to put a line per page and there is a lotta lotta pages so can't go around making images and putting them...

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The W3C has [a good introduction](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/).

In short:

HTML is a text markup language. Text means any characters, not just ones in ASCII.

1. Save your text using a character encoding that includes the characters you want (UTF-8 is a good bet). This will probably require configuring your editor in a way that is specific to the particular editor you are using. (Obviously it also requires that you have a way to input the characters you want)
2. Make sure your server sends the correct character encoding in the headers (how you do this depends on the server software you us)
3. If the document you serve over HTTP specifies its encoding internally, then make sure that is correct too
4. If anything happens to the document between you saving it and it being served up (e.g. being put in a database, being munged by a server side script, etc) then make sure that the encoding isn't mucked about with on the way.

You can also represent [any unicode character with ASCII](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.1)

Answer (score 65):

This is the answer that was required but everybody answered only part one of many.

- **Step 1 -** You cannot have the multilingual characters in unicode document.. convert the document to **`UTF-8`** document

> advanced editors don't make it simple for you... go low level... 
>   use notepad to save the document as meName.html & change the encoding
>  
>   type to UTF-8

- **Step 2 -** Mention in your html page that you are going to use such characters by

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  ```
- **Step 3 -** When you put in some characters make sure your container tags have the following 2 properties set

  ```
  dir='rtl'
  lang='ar'
  ```
- **Step 4 -** Get the characters from some specific tool\editor or online editor like i did with [Arabic-Keyboard.org](http://www.arabic-keyboard.org/editor/)

**example**

```
<p dir="rtl" lang="ar" style="color:#e0e0e0;font-size:20px;">رَبٍّ زِدْنٍي عِلمًا</p>
```

**NOTE:** font type, font family, font face setting will have no effect on special characters

Comment: What do you mean by "advanced editors don't do it"? Every editor I know of supports Unicode/UTF-8. That's on Windows at least...

Comment: "You cannot have the multilingual characters in unicode document" — The entire point of Unicode is to support multilingual characters. UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding.

Comment: "Mention in your html page that you are going to use such characters" — Real HTTP headers will override that.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't even know where to get Arabic characters, but you want to display them, then you're doing something wrong.

Save files containing Arabic characters with encoding UTF-8. A good editor allows you to set the character encoding.
In the HTML page, place the following after `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

If you're using XHTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

That's it.

An alternative way (without messing with the encoding of a file), is using HTML escape sequences. This website does that jobs for you: http://www.htmlescape.net/

Comment: do you see arabic........... see the question again... thats what arabic looks like

Comment: Yes I see arabic... Put an alternative way in my answer. Please review it.

Comment: THE "alternative" way in your question is called "Roman ($language)"
Roman Arabic, Roman French, Roman Urdu....

Roman French: bonjour (hello)
Roman Arabic: Ahla    (hello)
Roman German: Hallo \ Gutan Tag (hello)

Comment: I need special character in Arabic. But it always shows reverse. Everything is set - rtl , lang etc. ex : English : India !!!!  AND Arabic : !!!!الهند but when I render in HTML it comes as "الهند!!!!"

Answer (score 6):

You not only have to put the meta tag, telling that it is UTF-8 but really make the document UTF-8. You can do that with good editors (like notepad++) by converting them to "unicode" or "UTF-8 without BOM". Than you can simply use arabic characters

As this page is UTF-8, here are some examples (I hope I don't write anything rude here): شغف

If you use a server side scripting language make sure that it does not output the page in a different encoding. In PHP e.g. you can set it like this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Hey, I just copy-pasted some characters and wrote "Passion". Now you know how I feel about that page :)

Answer (score 6):

Won't you need the ensure the area where you display the Arabic is Right-to-Left orientated also?

e.g.

```
<p dir="rtl">
```

Comment: + <p dir="rtl" lang="AR"> رَبٍّ زِدْنٍي عِلمًا </p>
+ convert the document to UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

i edit the html page with notepad ++ ,set encoding to utf-8 and its work

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, by default text editors will not use UTF-8 as the standard encoding for documents.
However most editors will allow you to change that in the settings. Even for each specific document.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have `<meta charset="utf-8">` inside head block.