# Arabic text is showing ????(question marks) when selecting data from mysql in servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, arabic

I'm using this code

```
try {
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"; 

            Connection connection = null; 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");

            if(!connection.isClosed())
                System.out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
            ResultSet rs = null;


            Statement statement = null;
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            // sql query to retrieve values from the secified table.
            String QueryString = "SELECT `Text` FROM `card` WHERE `CardID`=1";
            rs = statement.executeQuery(QueryString);
            String arabictext ="";
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                arabictext += rs.getString(1);

            }
            rs.close();
            statement.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
        }
```

`Text` column in `card` table is `text` type and `utf8_unicode_ci` Collation. 
When I execute above query which fetch Arabic text then it didn't show in right format instead it show question marks like `?????`.
I print this on console and on jsp page, but it is showing `???` on both.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601760/html-arabic-support

Answer (score 0):

You might looking for [Character Encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/)

If you don't even know where to get Arabic characters, but you want to display them, then you're doing something wrong.

Save files containing Arabic characters with encoding UTF-8. A good editor allows you to set the character encoding. In the HTML page, place the following after :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

If you're using XHTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Refrence https://stackoverflow.com/a/3601802/2236219