# how can i give a multilingual support to HTML page?

Tags: html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="ar">
<body>
<p>بيـــان أعـــرف عميــــــلك</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this as my result : `Ø¨ÙŠÙ€Ù€Ù€Ø§Ù† Ø£Ø¹Ù€Ù€Ù€Ø±Ù Ø¹Ù…ÙŠÙ€Ù€Ù€Ù€Ù€Ù€Ù„Ùƒ`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: which language that is?

Comment: check this link:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

Comment: that language is arabic

Comment: source: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="ar">
<body>
<p>بيـــان أعـــرف عميــــــلك</p>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Put `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` in your `<head>` element.

Comment: check this link too:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601760/html-arabic-support

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I can't repeat your results in my browser. Where do you get your results?

However, I think what Xufox suggests is a good practice, to set charset as `utf-8` in you meta tag in `header`.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="ar">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<p>بيـــان أعـــرف عميــــــلك</p>

</body>
</html>
```