# html & css not applied to all browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser, display

I am giving a brief example with this Arabic letters see image attached

As long as the Arabic letters are separated there's no problem, I managed to colour them fine, but when connected it only works on firefox

safari and chrome break all connected letters

[broken letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuZ6K.png)
[connected letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPe7V.png)

```
<td onclick="playnadaba()">ن<span class="red">َ</span><span class="orange">&zwj;ض&zwj;</span><span class="red">َ</span>ب<span class="red">َ</span></td>
```

نَ‍ض‍َبَ

for some reason, I can see the text up correctly and I am using safari :/

Comment: maybe you already read this. 
Some instructions on using arabic character encoding
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601760/html-arabic-support#3606075
and additional information on character encoding
http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html

Comment: I have done all of this but not sure why it isn't working, and how is it working on this site :/